# How can I recreate a one-point perspective text effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to recreate the Captain Planet logo as shown below, but I'm having trouble with the one-point perspective effect on the text.

[image: Logo I'm trying to recreate]

My first thought was to use Photoshop's 3D effects, but it's slow, buggy and deprecated anyway. I then thought about a hard drop shadow effect, rasterizing the layer style and the text, then stroking the result, but the drop shadow doesn't do one point perspective, even if it did, if two parts of the shadow overlap, Photoshop treats it as one big area and just draws around the outside.

If all else fails, I'll have to draw it by hand, but 1) I'd like to avoid that and 2) I'm really curious if this can be done in Photoshop using something like filters or effects or transformation tools

Comment: Painting by hand is doing it in photoshop! Thogh why you would choose to use photoshop for this beats me.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I wouldn't draw artwork like this using Photoshop. Think about using vector software instead. The example drawing has almost certainly been drawn by hand (with or without software). I don't think any 3D effects or filters have been used here.

Comment: Also notice that this isn't just one-point perspective. The depth (z-axis) might be, you can check that by elongating the existing lines and see if they meet in one point. But both texts seem to have been distorted in two different ways *before* adding the perspective. Looks very deliberately "designed" to me and not entirely "mathematic". Could be mimicked in Illustrator using effects, but the result would be less charming..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is much easier to accomplish in an actual 3D application, or even in Illustrator. For me, Photoshop would be my *last* choice. The reality is it's a simple, flat extrusion without *any* shading or dynamic color - which is why I think Illustrator would actually be easier.

---

These are merely the **basic steps** I would use and are not intended to be a comprehensive "tutorial" on how to create the specific image in the question. There are further refinements which would be necessary to complete any final artwork (like the odd lines in the extrusion of the "C" and "P" for example - AI method.) My goal is to merely show the *tools* or application features used to create similar artwork. Obviously the sample image has some additional distortion applied to the type to create the added perspective skews.

---

The basics in Photoshop....

- Set Type
- `Edit > Transform > Warp` using **Arc** with 20% bend
  [image]
- `3D > New 3D Extrusion From Selected Layer`
- Rotate on the `Y` axis a bit
  [image]
- Increase Extrusion Depth on the **Properties Panel**
  [image]
- Reduce the `Taper` setting in the `Deform` area of the **Properties Panel**
  [image]
  [image]
- Find the `Extrusion Material` item on the **3D Panel** and click it. Then click the color box which appears on the **Properties Panel** to change the color of the extrusion.
  [image]
  [image]

From here it's manual labor to add the black lines on the extrusion. (...or I simply don't know enough regarding *how* to get those in Photoshop.)

Then repeat using similar, but somewhat reversed settings for the bottom word to get it to extrude and arc upward rather than downward.

---

## Using Illustrator....

- Set Type
- `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp` Choosing `Arc` and a 20% bend 
  [image]
- `Effect > 3D > 3D Extrude and Bevel`
- Rotate on the `Y` axis a bit
- Increase the `Perspective` setting quite a bit
- Increase the `Extrude Depth` setting
- You probably need to adjust light placement in the `More Options` area so you can see how it's actually extruding
  [image]
- Set the `Surface` to **No Shading** (trust me) and click `OK`
  [image]
- Choose `Object > Expand Appearance`
  [image]
- Choose `Object > Ungroup` 3 times
- Select the extrusion shapes and change their fill to blue and add a black stroke.
- Select the character shapes and add a black stroke

[image]

---

Comment: Y'know, it never occurred to me to use Illustrator. I've used Photoshop for almost 20 years, but barely touched Illustrator, except for one logo I designed about 10 years ago. This is a reminder for me to open it up and start learning again. I guess I also didn't know that Illustrator could do stuff like this easily. Thanks for the amazing answer. Very clear and answers my question!